# Convert escaped html ASCII codes to plain text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ascii

I'm looking to convert a string of html entities specifying ASCII codes (ie: &#97;) to the ASCII characters they represent (ie: a). I'm using a property of an object and trying to assign a value. For instance:

```
object.Text("");
```

When I pass is the string representing the entity, I get the same string back. I can't find the function to convert entities to the characters they represented.

Comment: The string "&#97;" is an HTML character entity. Do you mean to ask how to HTML-decode a string? That's not really what you've asked.

Comment: Ugh. Both the title and the text are poorly worded.

Comment: OK, I took a wack at it. Is it better this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) function.

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(97));
```

As you can see, you'll have to strip out the ampersand and pound sign.

Best regards...

Answer (score 22):

To convert all numerical character entities in a string to their character equivalents you can do this:

```
str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function (m, n) { return String.fromCharCode(n); })
```

Comment: I really like this solution, but do keep in mind that while `&#32;` will be converted, `&nbsp;` and other non-numeric escape codes will not.

Answer (score 1):

Check [String.fromCharCode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp).